# Adapter to use USB Flash drive as hard drive

Tags: usb, sata, flash-drive

So I'm building a budget PfSense Router and I would very much like to simply use a USB flash drive instead of a hard drive (to save money). There are plenty of SATA (Device side) -> USB (PC Side) adapters, but are there any for USB (Device Side) -> SATA (PC Side). If not, are there any SATA "Flash drives" that are essentially USB Flash Drives with sata connectors. I know of the Supermicro SATA DOMs but is there anything more affordable?

Comment: Can't you use the USB Drive as the boot drive? What I used to do on old FreeNas systems, but that was a LONNNNNnnnnnggggg time ago.

Comment: What about an SD card to SATA adapter? They seem to be available cheaply.